# how a user session-terminate works in linux?

Tags: linux, login, kde, logout, display-manager

I'm in arch linux with kde and sddm installed. When i logout i see black screen with a cursor on it. For some reason the sddm is not starting correctly after logout, dont know why. I wanna know what happens when I click logout, how the display manager is started after a logout and how the program which causes the logout (dont know what it is but guessing loginctl) knows what dm should be started in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

The display manager itself never actually stops running. Only the *greeter* (i.e. the special display showing the login screen) will exit when your own session is started. However, the display manager daemon continues running the whole time and watching the processes that it launched – as soon as your Xorg display server *or* your session leader process exits, the DM will clean up and launch a greeter display again.

I don't know about KDE, but usually the X display server and the desktop environment's "session manager" run side-by-side as children of the display manager:

```
sddm
|-- Xorg (serving display :0)
\-- gnome-session (client of display :0)
    |-- gnome-shell
    |-- gnome-settings-daemon
    |-- gnome-terminal
    \-- etc.
```

For a simple WM without a session manager, it would look the same – with the WM itself being the session leader:

```
sddm
|-- Xorg (serving display :0)
\-- i3wm (client of display :0)
    \-- xterm (client of display :0)
```

When you "log out", the session leader (i3wm, gnome-session, etc.) exits. The DM, upon noticing this, will kill the Xorg display server – causing all other apps to exit on their own as they lose the X11 connection.

Once both the X server and the session leader have exited, the DM will consider the session closed and will launch a "greeter" session showing you the login screen.

Note that although systemd-logind (loginctl) is optionally involved in session creation and cleanup, it doesn't actually affect the main procedure much – the same happens in non-systemd Linux as well.

Comment: thanks for the ans, i was literally searching for it for 2days...so it seems like when i log out, the "sddm" doesn't launch the greeter...do u know where the sddm conf file is or how to fix that?